# unable to start jenkins after editing matrix based security

Tags: java, exception, jenkins

I deployed latest jenkins war in tomcatrunning on my W$7 machine.During my first log in i configured something in matrix based security as explained [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Jenkins/article.html).After adding a user in the matrix, ia m unable to load the jenkins. The following error stack is shown. For complete stack trace please [visit here.](http://paste.opensuse.org/57267983).

Now, When i go to the login page, i could see the login form. Do we have any default login to proceed ?

Note: as described in that article i don't see create an account tab in the login page. Hence i am unable to proceed.

Stack trace :

```
hudson.security.AccessDeniedException2: anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission
at hudson.security.ACL.checkPermission(ACL.java:54)
at hudson.model.Node.checkPermission(Node.java:418)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.getTarget(Jenkins.java:3680)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:612)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:799)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:587)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:218)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
```

**Edit:**

I have also, redeployed the war.The issue was still there.

So then, i have downloaded the fresh war file from the JenKins site and deployed in the tomcat of xampp. When ever, i navigate to the jenkins app , the Java SE crashes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like you locked yourself out. Here are the lock picker instructions:

> ### Securing Jenkins
>
> ...
>
> #### [Disabling Security](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/operating/security/#disabling-security)
>
> One may accidentally set up security realm / authorization in such a way that you may no longer able to reconfigure Jenkins.
>
> When this happens, you can fix this by the following steps:
>
> 1. Stop Jenkins (the easiest way to do this is to stopthe servlet container.)
> 2. Go to `$JENKINS_HOME` in the file system and find `config.xml` file.
> 3. Open this file in the editor.
> 4. Look for the `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` element in this file.
> 5. Replace `true` with `false`
> 6. Remove the elements `authorizationStrategy` and `securityRealm`
> 7. Start Jenkins
> 8. When Jenkins comes back, it will be in an unsecured mode where everyone gets 
>      full access to the system.
>
> If this is still not working, trying renaming or deleting `config.xml`.

Comment: I couldn't found config.xml in my jenkins [v1.550].

Comment: I am in ubuntu 12.04 machine.root@bugcy013:~# su - jenkins
jenkins@bugcy013:~$ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins
jenkins@bugcy013:~$ cat /etc/passwd|grep jenkins
jenkins:x:123:65534:Jenkins,,,:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/bash
jenkins@bugcy013:~$

Comment: Stop Jenkins (the easiest way to do this is to kill the servlet container.)
Go to $JENKINS_HOME in the file system and find config.xml file.
Open this file in the editor.
Look for the <useSecurity>true</useSecurity> element in this file.
Replace true with false
Remove the elements authorizationStrategy and securityRealm
Start Jenkins

Comment: i am on ubuntu and jenkins is started successfuly but `$JENKINS_HOME` is empty . i tried `echo $JENKiNS_HOME`. empty

Comment: sudo find / -name "config.xml"

Comment: I was getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` because I locked myself out(...?). I think leaving the security realm elements intact while setting security to false caused that problem. Deleting the elements made it work again, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, i used windows and when i changed the config.xml it's works.

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers are wonderful, but nobody mentions the elephant - which is HOW does one get matrix security to work?  I went round and round with this until I happened upon what I think is the answer.

Here's what I did:

1. Disable security, as above
2. Go in to the 'configure global security' page
3. Select matrix security, and immediately enable all for anonymous
4. Add your users and set their permissions, making sure there is at least one administrator (I assume with all permissions).
5. Save, and make sure you are now logged in as an administrator.
6. Go back and turn off all but view permissions on anonymous (or whatever your 'anonymous access rules' are).
7. Save.

Done.

I believe the trick for getting past the 'Anonymous must have ' error is to be sure you are logged in **BEFORE** turning off anonymous admin privs.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps in below source.But still faced the same issue.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security

Finally, I tried to unistall and install the jenkins in another directory which help me to start working.

Hope it will help some one.

Answer (score -2):

you can do one thing

**stop the jenkins (using tomcat)**

go to config.xml present in JENKINS folder.
Look for the `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` element in this file.
Replace **true** with **false**.
Remove the elements authorizationStrategy and securityRealm
Start Jenkins
When Jenkins comes back, it's in the unsecured mode where everyone gets full access to the system

Comment: Agreed, the accepted answer is link-only, but that's basically just C&P of [the last section of the Jenkins page](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/operating/security/#disabling-security) linked there about three years before.

Comment: I guessed that it worked for you (otherwise you wouldn't put it as an answer here, hopefully ;) but that's not the point, which is that you gave an answer three years after and with the information of the accepted one rather than updating that answer which I did right now.

Answer (score -3):

Fixed by two simple steps:

1. Go to Jenkin Home
2. rename **config.xml**

Try launch the Jenkin

Comment: This is only the last resort (see the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20225117/1744774)) since you will reset all other configurations, too, which can be quite a lot.